# How to suppress Teradata warnings with CAST

Tags: teradata

Let's say I need to `CAST(birth_date AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY')`

If the `birth_date` field contains nulls or invalid characters it throws and untranslatable character error

Of course I can use the `regex`, `otranslate` but all that overcomplicates the `sql`

**Is there any way to suppress all these errors ?** `CAST` if you can, otherwise make it `null`?

Answer (score 2):

The burden of checking whether the data fits into the data type you wish to store it must reside somewhere. You could use `CASE {regular expression matching} THEN CAST() ELSE NULL END` which may be the cleanest way to address the data quality validation in your SQL.

Otherwise, pre-process your data file to replace bad data with a token you can replace with NULL in your SQL. You can consider doing this in PowerShell, UNIX shell scripting, or perhaps a third-party tool (e.g. address cleansing/formatting, etc.).

Comment: I know all the work arounds. It's just not worth it. Regex is an overkill ! ! ! Pre proccessing is super duper overkill ! ! !  I can't believe Teradata developers didn't introduce an `On Error Resume Next` mechanism . If Teradata encounteres a `bad` character, there should be and option to ignore that row. If there is no such a thing, then it must be introduced in Teradata 15. Otherwise IT SUCKS ! ! !  Let's say I need to quickly `JOIN` two tables and see the overlap . . . well I am NOT going to pre process this . Or think of a good `regex` :(

Comment: regex is a totally appropriate tool for this job. The statement would be something like: `SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_SIMILAR(<yourdatefield>, '^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$') = 1 THEN <yourdatefield> END FROM <yourtable>` Sometimes SQL statements are complicated and that's ok....

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no built in way to say `CAST(<field> as <datatype) IGNORING ERRORS AS <alias>` you could use a TPT script instead.

In TPT `APPLY` you can have an `INSERT` statement route errors into two different Error tables.

Something like the following would get you close. This is something that you would run after your dirty date table is loaded to get them into a clean date table.

```
DEFINE JOB DATA_insert_Example
(
        DEFINE OPERATOR data_insert_Example
        TYPE UPDATE
        SCHEMA *
        ATTRIBUTES
        (
               VARCHAR UserName,
               VARCHAR UserPassword,
               VARCHAR LogTable,
               VARCHAR TargetTable,
               INTEGER BufferSize,
               INTEGER ErrorLimit = 5,
               INTEGER MaxSessions = 4,
               INTEGER MinSessions = 1,
               INTEGER TenacityHours,
               INTEGER TenacitySleep,
               VARCHAR AccountID,
               VARCHAR AmpCheck,
               VARCHAR DeleteTask,
               VARCHAR ErrorTable1 = '<yourdatabase>.<yourcleantable>'||'_ET',
               VARCHAR ErrorTable2 = '<yourdatabase>.<yourcleantable>'||'_UV',
               VARCHAR NotifyExit,
               VARCHAR NotifyExitIsDLL,
               VARCHAR NotifyLevel,
               VARCHAR NotifyMethod,
               VARCHAR NotifyString,
               VARCHAR PauseAcq,
               VARCHAR PrivateLogName,
               VARCHAR TdpId,
               VARCHAR TraceLevel,
               VARCHAR WorkingDatabase = <yourdatabase>,
               VARCHAR WorkTable = '<yourdatabase>.<yourcleantable>'||'_Work'
        );

        DEFINE SCHEMA data_insert_schema
        (
                field1 VARCHAR(20),
                field2 VARCHAR(20),
                field3 VARCHAR(20),
                field4 VARCHAR(20)
        );

        DEFINE OPERATOR data_insert_export
        TYPE EXPORT
        SCHEMA W_0_s_DATA_esuh
        ATTRIBUTES
        (
                VARCHAR UserName,
                VARCHAR UserPassword,


  STEP UPS
    (
        APPLY
        (
            'INSERT INTO <yourdatabase>.<yourcleantable> 
                field1,
                field2,
                field3,
                field4
             VALUES (
                :field1,
                :field2,
                :field3,
                :field4,
              )';

        )   


        TO OPERATOR
        (
                data_insert_Example[1]

                ATTRIBUTES
                (
                        UserName = <yourusername>,
                        UserPassword = <yourpass>,
                        LogTable = <yourdatabase>.<yourcleantable> ||'_LOG',
                        TargetTable = <yourdatabase>.<yourcleantable> ,
                        TdpId = <yourserverip/address>
                )
        )
        SELECT * FROM OPERATOR
        (
                data_insert_export[1]

            ATTRIBUTES
            (
                    UserName = <yourusername>,
                    UserPassword = <yourpassword>,
                    SelectStmt = 'SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4 FROM <yourdatabase>.<yourtable> ;',
                    TdpId = '<yourserverip/address>'
            )
        );       
    );
)
```

Obviously, though, this is quite a bit more overkill than a simple REGEX. RegEx feels way overwhelming when you first start using it, but I think it's a completely reasonable usecase for checking dates stored as string literals before trying to convert them into their proper data type.

Overall, it sounds like you have garbage for data, so I totally get the frustration. Unfortunately for garbage data there is no magic bullet. You'll need some decent ETL between the garbage and your clean output.

Comment: Nice alternative @JNevill!

Comment: I should mention that you can work with that ERRORLIMIT attribute on the UPDATE OPERATOR so the TPT will keep chugging and end with a Status 0. Otherwise you'll end up with a checkpoint file and restarts and yuck.